# React and d3 Importing data in react Component - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts, redux

I have implemented this [chart](http://codepen.io/Mannaio/pen/KNeeEd?editors=1010) example in my application

See the image on how this is composed

[image]

The problem is that i can only show my charts correctly filled with the data if my `nums` data are hardcoded like this `const nums = [32, 19, 47, 38, 17, 62, 94, 21, 59, 62];`

export default class ChartsGrid extends React.Component{

```
  render() {

    const view = [480, 320];
    const trbl = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    const horizontalAxisHeight = 30;
    const verticalAxisWidth = 42;
    const nums = [32, 19, 47, 38, 17, 62, 94, 21, 59, 62];

    return (
      <div className="grid">
          <LineChart {...{view, trbl, nums, horizontalAxisHeight, verticalAxisWidth}} />
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

If i declare my data as props `const { nums } = this.props;` in my `ChartsGrid` component then i get this error in my `LineChart` Component

***TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined***

This is beacuse it is complaining about the `nums` in the render function in `LineChart`

```
const {view, trbl, nums, horizontalAxisHeight, verticalAxisWidth} = this.props;
```

my `nums` data are actually consumible in the store (I can see it in the console)

*num.js*

```
const nums = [32, 19, 47, 38, 17, 62, 94, 21, 59, 62];

export default nums;
```

*reducer.js*

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';

import nums from './nums';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({nums, routing: routerReducer });

export default rootReducer;
```

*store*

```
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

This the logic to store the data *num.js*

so why then LineChart can not read them?

Comment: You included the `redux` tag. Can you include your `connect` code that connects your component to the store?

Comment: update the question with the store logic

Comment: This still doesn't show your component being connected to the store. If it isn't, I can provide an answer showing how it should be, but if it is, please include that code because the issue would probably be in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an empty array to avoid this issue, as below

```
const nums  = this.props.nums || [];
```

You you should check why this property is coming as null or undefined first. There must be some logical error in the part where you are assign the prop.

Comment: it returns empty obviously

Comment: Yeah, or use a default prop of `[]` instead of needing to place a fallback wherever it's accessed